# Is it possible to create a static variable that will only be accessed by two classes?

Tags: java, variables, static

for example suppose that we have the classes A, B, C, D, E

now A has a public static int variable

I want this variable to be visible only in A and B classes, not in C,D,E.

Is it possible to do this, without making the variable protected and using inheritance?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Put classes A and B in their own package, and give the field default (package) visibility. (Don't give it a `public`, `protected` or `private` specifier).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use any visibility modifier, the member will have package level visibility and you could put A and B in the same package and C, D, E in a different package.

However, there's a definite [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) here...

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a static getter. Inside that getter, you can throw an Exception, catch it, check the caller and then grant access or throw an access denied exception.

Other than that, the answer lies in inheritance and other well-known OO solutions.

Comment: That sounds like an extremely smelly, hacked way to implement this. Do **not** recommend.

Comment: I don't approve of this answer, but at least use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` instead of throwing exceptions.

Comment: Well me neither. But why would you go against the *definition* of a `public static` variable in the first place? The whole question sounds fishy to me.

Comment: @PhilippReichart Good idea. Forgot about `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` completely.

Comment: You don't need to throw and catch the exception, all you need to do is create it. `(new Exception()).getStackTrace()` is actually what `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` uses. @PhilippReichart

Comment: In terms of performance, that's no different than actually throwing and catching it. Registering the exception with JVM and creating the stack trace is the actual time consuming part.

Answer (score 0):

It not possible. If Class B is only be class A you could use a inner class.

Comment: it is possible.  the real question is is it worthwhile

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to throw A and B in a separate package and make the variable only visible to the members of the package. To do that you just have to leave away the visibility keyword (e.g. public or protected). The default visibility for variables in Java is package.

Answer (score 0):

aVar and bVar are public and static but only accessible from classes A and B (and AB).

`

```
public class AB
{
          private static class A
           {
                       public static int aVar ;
            }


           private static class B
           {
                        public static int bVar ;
           }
}
```

`